# ADO Count Type Mismatch

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I am referring from one of l my previous post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621564/syntax-of-select-count-in-ado

I have an ADO connection between my Excel file and another Excel file that works correctly

```
Set adoConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & CStr("F:\Tools\FDd_v1.3.xlsm") & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"";"
```

I am trying to write in Excel/VBA this request that result with a `Error Type Mismatch`

```
Dim TCode As String
Dim at As Long    
TCode = WS.Range("J" & CStr(c)).Value & WS.Range("L" & CStr(c)).Value
at = "Count * from [Trader$C2:C5000] where [Trader_ID]=" & CStr(TCode)
```

I tried as well with `at = "Count * from [Trader$C2:C5000] where [Trader$C2:C5000]=" & CStr(TCode)` but had same error.  `[Trader_ID]` is the Header of the column C.  Thxx

Comment: What is `at` in that last line, and what's the value in `TCode` ?

Comment: Value in `TCode` is a 6 letters Code  for example `DBABJC`...`at` should be a number... I want to count how many times we have the value `DBABJC` in the column `Trader$C2:C5000`... So `at` is a number

Comment: If TCode is not numeric then you should put single-quotes around it in your SQL.  And you cannot run SQL simply by assigning the string to a variable where you'd like the return value to go...  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692882.aspx for how to run your SQL and return a recordset.

Comment: Tried like this `at = "Count * from [Trader$C2:C5000] where [Trader_ID]=" & "'TCode'"` but not working.... didnt understand your point about assigning the string to a variable

Comment: See the link I posted: if you can't get that working then update your question with your full code.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the connection a little differently.  Here I'm returning a record set and then getting the count from the results.

```
Sub countRecordset()
    Dim myConnection As String
    Dim myRecordset As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim mySQL As String

    myConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & CStr("F:\Tools\FDd_v1.3.xlsm") & _
               "Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes"

    Dim TCode As String
    Dim at As Long
    TCode = WS.Range("J" & CStr(c)).Value & WS.Range("L" & CStr(c)).Value

    mySQL = "SELECT * from [Trader$C2:C5000] where [Trader_ID]=" & CStr(TCode)

    Set myRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    myRecordset.Open mySQL, myConnection, adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified

    MsgBox myRecordset.Fields.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like smart to me ... but still have an error `No value given for one or more required parameters` ... I guess it is an error in the names of my data.  My Sheet name is `Trader`, in this sheet I have a Data Table named `Traders`... I care on the Column C that have `Trader_ID` as header